# Почему select2 не работает?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Использую библиотеку select2. Надо сделать селект ридонли. Пишу `$('#mySelect').select2('readonly', true)` и получаю ошибку:

```
core.min.js:275 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (core.min.js:275)
    at Function.each (core.min.js:7)
    at e.fn.init.each (core.min.js:7)
    at e.fn.init.a.fn.select2 (core.min.js:275)
    at <anonymous>:1:41
```

Баг библиотеки? Кто-то сталкивался? На какой версии нет такого?

P.S. Предыдущий вариант использования нашел в гугле, но в доках указан вроде такой еще: `.select2({readonly: true})`. Ошибки не возникает, но селект становится по другому стилизован и он все еще не ридонли.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы настраивать select2 в него нужно передавать объект **.select2({readonly: true})** при начальной инициализации. Вроде свойства **readonly** у select2 нету, но есть **disabled**. А вам .select2({disabled: true}) так не подойдёт?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам это подойдет:

```js
$("#e1").select2({
  disabled: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="e1">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

http://select2.github.io/select2/